# Querying with the Akka.net ask pattern

Tags: c#, iqueryable, akka.net

I has an restful API which uses an odata request to query data front the database. 
I'm looking to start to swapping out domain logic with akka.net but I don't want to change the clients. 
Is there any way I can hook the ask pattern to use IQueryable?

Comment: On the JVM side similar feature can be achieved using akka-stream. However until it's ported on .NET, you'd need to implement similar (simplified) pattern by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Any pointers on how to do this or where to look for an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've described in comment, this feature will be available as part of reactive streams in Akka.Streams plugin in the future. It'll allow to create dynamic push-pull based, buffered data flows.

However you can implement progressive `IEnumerable` of responses by yourself. I've created a primitive [snippet](https://gist.github.com/Horusiath/e0c0bfc9eabbe096cb21), that may be used along with LINQ.